# Flexible recursive XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I'm trying to create a validation schema for this sample XML. I already tried using recursive definitions, but cannot find a proper way. Please note that IF and ELSE elements can be nested any number of times, and ACTIONx elements can appear in any order. Also note that every element has its own possibly different attributes.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KEYPRESS Buffer="1">
    <ACTION1 Index="15" />
    <IF Condition="0">
        <IF Condition="1">
            <ACTION1 Index="14" />
            <ELSE>
                <ACTION2 Measure="whatever" />
            </ELSE>
        </IF>
    
        <IF Condition="2">
            <IF Condition="5">
                <ACTION2 Measure="whatelse" />
                <ACTION3 Type="Flag"  />
            </IF>
            <ELSE>
                <ACTION1 Index="0" />
                <ACTION3 Type="Other" />
                <IF Condition="1">
                    <ACTION3 Type="Flag" />
                </IF>
            </ELSE>
        </IF>
    </IF>
</KEYPRESS>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

*** EDIT ***
Many thanks to [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay), excellent solution!
I'm posting here the resulting schema, in case someone might be interested.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="INSTRUCTION" abstract="true"/>

    <xs:element name="ACTION1" substitutionGroup="INSTRUCTION">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ACTION2" substitutionGroup="INSTRUCTION">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ACTION3" substitutionGroup="INSTRUCTION">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="IF" substitutionGroup="INSTRUCTION">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="INSTRUCTION" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="ELSE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Condition" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="KEYPRESS" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="INSTRUCTION" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="KeySeq" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Buffer" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ELSE" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="INSTRUCTION" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of structure is what substitution groups are for.

Define an abstract element `INSTRUCTION`, and then define `IF`, `ACTION1`, `ACTION2`, and `ACTION3` as members of the substitution group of `INSTRUCTION`, each with its own type definition defining the permitted attributes. The content model of `KEYPRESS` and `ELSE` appears to be `INSTRUCTION*` (a sequence of 0 or more instructions), and the content model of `IF` appears to be `(INSTRUCTION*, ELSE?)` (a sequence of 0 or more instructions followed optionally by an `ELSE`).

(`ELSE` is not a member of the substitution group, because it can't appear anywhere an instruction appears).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can define a schema with variable element names.

An [element declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Element_Declaration_details) requires a name. The value is of the type `xs:NCName`, which is just a string and not a pattern. In order to write a schema, you have to find out the maximum number of action elements. And you have to define a complexType for every single element. I do not think you want to do this.

You XML file has been designed by someone, who does not know much about XML. You better tell him, that the format has to be redesigned. Instead of

```
<ACTION1 ...>
```

use

```
<ACTION N="1" ...>
```

and the schema validation will be easy.

Comment: Redesigning actions according to your suggestion is feasable, but still I don't see how to declare the <IF> and <ELSE> elements.

Comment: I don't agree that this XML is badly designed (except possibly for the choice of element names ACTION1 etc - but I imagine these are placeholders). On the contrary, it is exactly how I would expect a recursive instruction structure to be modelled. The XSLT vocabulary has a similar structure (but with different instruction names) and it's modelled using a recursive and extensible schema using substitution groups.

Comment: I would normally give the advice that `<ACTION1>` should be `<ACTION N="1">`, but not if `ACTION1` and `ACTION2` have different content models (which would then require conditional type assignment in XSD 1.1). Of course it would be better to choose more descriptive names such as BEND and STRETCH rather than ACTION1 and ACTION2.

Comment: ACTIONx are just placeholders for simplifying the structure: they actually have different names